# UINavigationBar overlaps UITableView when programmatically setting prompt

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` which contains a `UITableViewController`. This navigation controller pushes other UITableViewControllers around and eventually these table view controllers will have a prompt.

The problem is when I set this prompt programmatically it overlaps the content of the table view underneath it.

[image]

(A search bar is being hidden by the navigation bar)

I was looking around in SO and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460305/uinavigationbar-prompt-overlaps-the-screen-content). I tried the suggestion there in two different ways in the affected view controller but nothing changed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Add Anime or Manga", comment: "")
    self.navigationItem.prompt = NSLocalizedString("Search media belonging to this series.",  comment: "")
}
```

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Add Anime or Manga", comment: "")
    self.navigationItem.prompt = NSLocalizedString("Search media belonging to this series.",  comment: "")
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
}
```

A comment in that same answer linked to [this Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) on preventing views from overlapping each other. The problem is `UITableViewController` doesn't appear to have top/bottom layout guides so I can't create a constraint ([another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085152/xcode-5-not-displaying-top-bottom-layout-guides-for-tableviewcontrollers) says having said layouts in table view controllers is irrelevant).

As such I have exhausted all my options.

Comment: Have you found how to work it out? I'm facing the exact same problem, just with a `UIViewController` and a `UITableView`. Thanks.

Comment: @Zaphod Unfortunately no. I ended up adapting my design to something else.

Comment: So did I... Well, may be an iOS bug. Are you aware of some kind of radar opened on the subject?

Answer (score 6):

I have tried to reproduce your problem and it seems that when not all the `viewControllers` have a prompt the `navigationBar` is somehow not resizing properly.

It seems you need to somehow trigger the layouting for the `UINavigationController`. The only way I could make it work properly was by adding this in `viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

}
```

Maybe this prompt is meant to be used consistently across the entire application (meaning having one for all viewControllers or none of them), that's why the `UINavigationController` does not layout it's subviews when it changes.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that setNavigationBarHidden also expecteds a bool parameter for animation, but when the navbar reappears, it still overlaps. I will go ahead and open a bug report with Apple. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Select your TableViewController from document outline and change the value to translucent navigation bar of top bar in attributes inspector. Be sure that you will not select uitableview you should select your your table view controller(aka File's Owner) from document outline.

Comment: Forgot to mention I did that. It works fine if I set the prompt before that navigationItem is created, but not when I set it dynamically.

Comment: Did you try [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set prompt only if view did appear, then it works:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         navigationItem.prompt = "your prompt here"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2019 and this is still not fixed. *Slow Clap.* I refuse to be cowed by such things so I hammered `iOS` into submission with the dirtiest trick in the book. I fixed this by doing a disgusting `-44` "y trick" on the `UINavigation` while placing the `UITableView` in `top 44`, I know it's stupid, but it works.. I am sure new fangled phones will ruin my genius.. but hey ho.. I have lazily left irrelevant code (because I am idle) but hopefully you can see what I did.

**WITHOUT THE y: -44 Hack**
[image]
**WITH THE y: -44 Hack**
[image]

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -44, width: screenSize.width, height: 44)) //<<--note minus 44
navBar.barTintColor = Globals.Color_BackgroundGrey()
navBar.isTranslucent = false
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0); //<--note plus 44
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Boaty Mc Boatface")
let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(done))
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
view.addSubview(navBar)
```