# UINavigationItem Prompt Animation Issue

Tags: uinavigationitem

I have two `UITableViewController`s that are connected via a `Show` segue. The `prompt` property of `UINavigationItem` is set on both view controllers in Interface Builder. When the first view controller is shown, the prompt and navigation bar are both displayed properly, however, when performing a segue to the second view controller, the `title` and the back button animate undesirably. I have tried setting the prompts programmatically in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, and the `viewDidAppear:` methods of both view controllers, but I get the same effect.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I don't want to resort to a custom view for the `titleView` because I prefer the stock functionality, but I am not able to figure out how to fix the undesirable animation.

Here is a [video](http://youtu.be/0A_wEyj1Gaw) if the animation in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like this is an issue with the way that the `UINavigationItem` is laid out when showing the next view controller.

According to [Catalina T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4112491/catalina-t) in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053198/uinavigationbar-overlaps-uitableview-when-programatically-setting-prompt#answer-29111150) to a similar question, making two calls to set the `hidden` property of the navigation bar to `true` and then again to `false` in `viewWillAppear:` seems to get by this issue.